# How to link a field to node title in view

Tags: views

I created a content type. I have three fields: title, body, city.

I added two contents.

I can see nodes at:

http://www.example.com/?q=content/we-buy-houses-nj

http://www.example.com/?q=content/we-buy-houses-va

I created a view as following:
I added **title** field first (excluded from display).
I selected city field. For rewrite results, change the path to "content/[title]"

**Result:**

I can see the city field is hyperlinked. When I click each link, I get URL as following and page can not be found:

http://www.example.com/?q=content/We%20Buy%20Houses

http://www.example.com/?q=content/We%20Buy%20Houses

How do I remove the **%20** so page can be found in my case?

[image]

Comment: **Just a side note:** You should enable clean urls by going to `/admin/config/search/clean-urls`. This will get rid off the `?q=` part which is bad for SEO.

Comment: Thank you. It was a helpful tips. I just cleaned the urls. Now, I do not see ?q=.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `%20` because the browser replaces/fixes/auto-corrects the empty space between your title with `%20` as empty spaces are not allowed in URLs.

EX: If you try to go to `drupal.org/Hello World`, browser url changes/corrects it to `drupal.org/Hello%20World`.

---

Here is another *possible* option:

Add `Path` as a field, and checkmark exclude from display.

Make sure `Content: Path` is above `Content: Cities`, if not please re-arrange it.

Then in cities, for link path put `[path]`